# Проблемы с сетью в приложении для телефона

Tags: сеть, сокет

Я решил протестировать как работает socket в приложении для телефона. Весь код написан на Python, прелбразовывал APK файл через Buildozer, писал на Kivy. И всё вроде бы работает как и задумывалось, при открытии приложения на сервер отправляется текст Hello World. Но это работает только в моей домашней сети, от мобильного интернета оно уже не работает(та же ситуация была и с Flutter, поэтому я думаю что проблема не совсем в коде).
Я проверил с чем это работает и вот: 1. В двух терминалах на моём ПК оно работает. 2. Сервер у меня на ПК, а клиент у друга на ПК оно работает. 3. Сервер у меня на ПК, приложение на телефоне в моей сети оно работает.
Адрес на который клиент отправляет информацию я нашёл на странице моего роутера в браузере(IP-адрес:10.2.##.1##(Динамический IP-адрес)). Подскажите пожалуйста в чём может быть проблема?

Comment: В том, что этот IP-адрес не внешний и предназначен для работы только внутри локальной сети. Просите внешний IP-адрес у вашего интернет-провайдера

Comment: Спасибо! Но почему тогда оно работает с моим другом?

Comment: Если у него тот же интернет-провайдер, то вероятно потому что вы находитесь в общей локальной сети этого самого провайдера

Comment: Да, у него тот же провайдер, спасибо за ответ!